# jQuery tablesorter: TypeError: s[1] is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

i have table and after updating it by JS i run update trigger (like it was said a lot of times in such cases) but it doesn't working and FireBug says: "TypeError: s[1] is undefined".

```
// in $(document).ready()
$('#stattable').tablesorter();

// after updating table content
$('#stattable').triggerHandler('update');
$('#stattable').trigger('sorton', [[1, 1], [0, 0]]);
$('#stattable').trigger('appendCache');
```

HTML code:

```
<table id="stattable">
 <thead>
  <tr><th>Producer</th><th>Value</th><th>Amount</th></tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <!-- here dynamically generated data -->
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
  <tr><td>SUM:</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
 </tfoot> 
</table>
```

Dynamic data is in format:

```
<tr>
 <td>Ford</td>
 <td>1999.90</td>
 <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Renault</td>
 <td>345.1</td>
 <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Mitsubishi</td>
 <td>0</td>
 <td>0</td>
</tr>
... etc.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see the associated HTML? Or even better a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle it's going to be hard... because it's commercial project...

Comment: With dummy data. Without it, we can't "debug" it for you.

Comment: what does 'sorton' do? Are you sure that the array is being transferred correctly?

Comment: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: @marverix it works http://jsfiddle.net/tp8Zs/1/ . Now I guess, you're not telling something important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) an event, you need to wrap the extra parameters in square brackets:

```
$('selector').trigger('event', [ parameters ]);
```

So in this case, the sortList is missing an extra set of brackets:

```
$('#stattable').trigger('sorton', [ [[1, 1], [0, 0]] ]);
```